# drawerOpened property dont work in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

I use litElement with vaadin and have next code

```
 <vaadin-app-layout .drawerOpened='false'>
            <vaadin-drawer-toggle slot="navbar" ></vaadin-drawer-toggle>              
            <vaadin-tabs selected="-100" slot="drawer" orientation="vertical" theme="minimal" style="margin: 0 auto; flex: 1;">
                 ${this.renderTabsDependOnStatusAccess()}
             </vaadin-tabs>
              <div class="content" >
                 <div id="outlet"></div>
               </div>
           </vaadin-app-layout>
```

but my vaadin-drawer-toggle component is still open, how can I make it private by default and wats wrong with my example

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this component, but I'll guess that in JS it's `drawerOpened` while in HTML it's `drawer-opened`. Also, boolean attributes are usually present or not, so instead of `drawer-opened="false"` you probably just remove it. Plain `drawer-opened` would be `true`.

If this HTML or in the LitElement `render()`? In the latter you may want to use `?drawer-opened="${this.isDrawerOpen}"` and toggle a property `this.isDrawerOpen`

Comment: this litElement renderer, and even when I use ?drawerOpened="${false}" or ?drawer -opened="${false}" it still dont work

Comment: and I didnt find any example with closed component(

Comment: In lit-html templates, property bindings are done with a dot prefix before the property name: `<vaadin-app-layout  .drawerOpened='false'>`. Also, don't leave spaces before and after the equals sign, that’s invalid HTML.

Comment: <vaadin-app-layout .drawerOpened='false'> didnt help(

Comment: I saw there is setDrawerOpened method to change the drawer state. And I can't find any info whether drawerOpened is private or public property.  So I think you will try by calling the method instead of property binding?